# Using Object.assign with React.Component

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, composition

I pulled this example code together and wanted to see why React is throwing an error. I have hit a wall in trying to explain this as an alternative to using descendants of React.Component.

```
const App = ({children}) => (
  <div className="app">
    { children }
  </div>
);

const Example = Object.assign(
  {},
  React.Component,
  {
    render () {
      return (
        <h1>Does this work?</h1>
      );
    }
  }
);


ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <Example />
  </App>,
  document.querySelector('#target')
);
```

Comment: The real question is why you even expected it to work. `React.Component` is a constructor. If you want to extend react component use `class Example extend React.Component`.

Comment: The point is to move away from `createClass` and using class extensions of `Component`, to truly use composition instead of inheritance. By extending the `React.Component` constructor, you are creating descendants of the pseudo-class which seems unavoidable. I had hoped to get an explanation other than the framework does not support that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works without `createClass` or `extends`

```
const Example = (props, context) => Object.assign(
  {},
  Object.create(React.Component.prototype),
  {
    props, context,
    state: {text: 'acutally'},
    render () {
      return (
        <span>This {this.state.text} works</span>
      );
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is simply not supposed to work.

You are trying to create a React Component using an unsupported way. The three ways to create a proper React component is with :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { //class implementation
}
let MyComponent = React.createClass({ // class implementation
});
function MyCompent (props, context) { // component render method
}
```

Basically it boils down to :

- declaring a class (1st form) which extends *React.Component*.
- creating a class from an object (2nd form) both return some kind of a "constructor" object.
- implementing a render function.

You give each of these forms to React to update and render the component tree.

What you did was trying (I guess) to create an instance of React.Component with *Object.assign* and then passing it to React to render.

React does not work this way. Instead you give it either a "constructor" (first 2 forms) which implements #render() => reactElement ( a method which returns React Elements and not Components) or you pass it a function which also returns React Elements.

PS : To create an *instance* of a class without using *new*, Es5 introduced *Object.create*:

```
var o = Object.create(proto); // o.__proto__ === proto
// the returned object has the supplied arguments as prototype.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the legacy (pre-ES6) syntax:

```
const Example = React.createClass({
    render () {
      return (
        <h1>Does this work?</h1>
      );
    }
  });
```

More information can be found in the [documentation on using React without ES6](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html).